# Why does this basic list operator take much longer than this one on long lists in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

So in elixir 1.3.2, I create 2 large lists:

```
a = Enum.to_list(10..1_000_001)
b = Enum.to_list(1..1_000_000)
```

I notice that `a++b` returns a result quickly but `a--b` takes a long time to return a result.  Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

I think to combine arrays there only thing that needs to be done is  to allocate memory for the new array and then put but both arrays in allocated memory.

To calculate difference of two arrays each element of the second array is searched in the first array (element is removed from the first array when it is found).

The complexity of adding is O(n) and the complexity of subtraction is O(n2).

From [the Kernel docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html):

The [complexity of a ++ b](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#++/2) is proportional to length(a), so avoid repeatedly appending to lists of arbitrary length, e.g. list ++ [item].

The [complexity of a -- b](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2) is proportional to length(a) * length(b), meaning that it will be very slow if both a and b are long lists. In such cases, consider converting each list to a [MapSet](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html) and using [MapSet.difference/2](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html#difference/2).

Comment: Exactly this, but I don't think that `++` even has the allocation step you're talking about - it would just move some references to "point" to the joined list rather than having to copy them (I think).